# How can an open source project attract new contributors?

Tags: contributor, project-management

One of the most common things that I see in open source projects is that they are maintained by a single developer. In my opinion, this often leads to abandoned projects due to the lack of time (or motivation) from the creator of the project and (if the project gains popularity) too many feature requests for a single person to deal with.

On the other hand, many open source projects have several programmers but do not have any designer...which ends with:

- Good programs that are not very user-friendly and therefore have a very small user base
- Lack of originality in those projects, which results in a slower gain of popularity among users

Are there any "thumb" rules or recommendations to attract more contributors to join an open source project?